# How to remap Control+Space to Return?

Tags: linux, input, terminal, keyboard

I want control+space to work as enter(Return) through out the entire linux system, not only in terminal.

If this is not possible, at least in terminal.
For example, I'm using urxvt, and in my ~/.Xresources I have

`URxvt*keysym.Control-Space: \036`

However this doesn't work.

Comment: This question has been moved to superuser with a universal solution. https://superuser.com/questions/990944/remap-controlspace-to-behave-like-return-enter-key-compatible-with-vim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ASCII carriage return is `^M`, decimal 13, octal 15.  That would make your suggested setting

```
URxvt*keysym.Control-Space: \015
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but the terminal didn't press enter when I hit control space. Can I enter a command with this?

Comment: I think your solution is correct, it's just my keysym doesn't work at all, thank you